# IntellJ IDEA with Tomcat, how to SPEED UP static resources updating?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, local, frontend

Recently I'm working with a Java team, I don't know anything about Java before, I'm in charge of front-end development. Now I'm struggling with a problem and need some advice.

For short, I know how to update static files automatically when file changes has been saved in Tomcat, but this process takes too long, I have to keep waiting and waiting for browser finally knowing about those updates, this may take 5, 8, even 10+ seconds.

I'm missing my Node.js env now, missing Grunt, live-reload, I can't stand any more! Now I just want to know, is there any way to make the change happen instantly? Or using Gruntjs and Tomcat together? Because they don't planned to implement CORS/JSONP or any sort of easy way to let client-side fetch API remotely. If I serving static files with Gruntjs, I can't access to api response from Tomcat server... or someone tell me how to? I hate Java...forgive me.

Comment: If it's a Tomcat servlet container, it's likely using JSPs.  It's probably just the nature of the application that it takes a while for it to reload the JSP and refresh the servlet.  Things aren't nearly as snappy as they are with Grunt.  Now, unless your page is served primarily by Node.js, there wouldn't be any way to achieve the same reload time with just Tomcat and JSPs.

Comment: @Makoto Is this 'nature of servlet container' also affect the static files? Such as HTML/CSS/Images?